# MySQL gem Failed to Build: Ruby(1.8.7) Rails(2.0.2)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

`Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension`
[image: error]

Running `bundle install` display that error above.

This project has an old version of ruby(1.8.7) and rails(2.0.2).

Installed already the MySQL following this reference:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

Added this to gemfile `gem 'mysql', '~> 2.9', '>= 2.9.1'`.

I was currently working on upgrading the ruby and rails version of this project into latest.
Need a helping hand out there. Thanks.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-122-generic x86_64)

This is the error display on my terminal:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try to run `gem install mysql - v '2.9.1'` as suggested in the error message?

Comment: @spickermann yes i did install that also.

Comment: And what happened when you did that? Was there an error message too? What did it say?

Comment: @Mike `gem install mysql ...` installs the mysql gem, not MySQL itself. It's the command that bundler runs under the hood. If you can install the gem successfully manually, bundler should succeed, too. Otherwise, there should be a build log with additional debugging information, usually mentioned in bundler's output.

Comment: @spickermann running that throws an error also. ERROR:  Error installing mysql: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: @Stefan i uploaded an image about the error.

Comment: A quick google search for _"unknown type name my_bool"_ links the issue to MySQL 8 [removing the my_bool type](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87337). You probably have to install an older MySQL version for that gem (5.x should work).

Comment: @Stefan okay, i will try that.

Comment: I would look into setting up a Docker container so that you can set it up with various versions of MySQL and Ruby and not have to monkey around with the system wide installation. It's going to be pretty vital to  preserve your sanity and to avoid "it works for me!" issues if you're multiple devs on the team. https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql